# Bad Portable AC Unit Plug Circuit

Tags: electrical, wiring, repair, switch

Model: LG LP1414GXR

The unit was running fine but it appears the plug circuitry overheated and went bad. Is it okay to replace the existing plug by cutting it off at the end and replacing it with a new socket that’s rated the same?

From the pictures I’ve attached you can see the circuitry and wiring. There is a fourth wire (non insulated) in the background and I’m uncertain of its purpose. I haven’t been able to find any information with a plug schematic for this unit. I don’t want to leave it disconnected in case it’s a safety feature.

Is there a plug replacement that someone might be able to recommend. The home improvement stores sell a GFCI plug replacement but it only have 3 terminals. I contacted LG to get a new power cord but it cost $120. Greedy a holes!

[image: Plug]

Comment: Looks like a solenoid. Could that be what the bare wire is powering? I've never seen soldered joints like that before. Is that from the factory?

Comment: Yes, it’s factory. I suppose it could be powering it—for what purpose?

Comment: Not sure. Could it be a built-in thermal disconnect to protect the appliance from overheating?

Comment: Try this spec sheet: http://gscs-b2c.lge.com/downloadFile?fileId=KROWM000577223.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the instructions that was helpful in my search for a replacement. I came across [this](https://www.amazon.com/OAONAN-Replacement-Interrupter-Protection-Conditioner/dp/B06XPFB6ND/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1549365484&sr=8-6&keywords=circuit+breaker+plug/). Might give it a try.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the board on the other side of the plug? I suspect it's a LCDI (Leakage Current Detector Interruptor) plug, but seeing the board would help verify that...

Comment: @wellington -- I wouldn't use some random garbo thing off of Amazon Marketplace for this...

Comment: I accidentally tossed it in the trash when I was cleaning up. Of course my new year resolution to stop collecting clutter has already backfired. Despite not being able to post a photo for you, is there plug you can recommend?